# While loop end condition

Tags: java, while-loop

This startles me.  The following test fails; the loop finishes with i having the value 9, not 8.  Can you explain it?

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class TestDoWhile extends TestCase {
    final int LIMIT = 8;

    public void testDoWhile() throws Exception {
        int i = 0;
        do {
        } while (i++ < LIMIT);
        assertEquals(LIMIT, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: i would personally avoid any code which can make operator precedence confused...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
++i < LIMIT
```

the way you have it the condition is evaluated, and *then* i is incremented. If you do the above, i will be incremented before the evaluation.

Comment: D'oh!  Thank you.  I'll accept your answer as soon as the system permits.

Answer (score 4):

The reason must be the i++ which is incrementing the variable one last time after the last evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

During the pass through the loop when i is 8, the ++ increments it to 9, but being a post-increment operator, it's the original 8 compared to LIMIT, which fails and exits the loop.

Answer (score 0):

i++ means increment i after its use on this expression.  Try ++i to get the expected result.

/Victor